# Power Apps Lookup data type errors

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a power apps form which asks for a user to enter an employee's name and a email address.
I want to autofill the email address based on the user's response, so for example if they type John Doe it will fill in the email.

I have a table with all of the employee names and email addresses and I am trying to do a lookup in the email address however am getting data type errors.

This is the formula I am using but I have tried variations where I use `Text()` and .Text to try to get around it with no luck.
Also I have double checked all of my data types are already set as text so not sure where the issue is.

```
LookUp(EmployeeLookup,'Employee Name' = DataCardValue.Text, 'Employee Email')
```

I have also tried to deal with blanks and errors with the below but still not working:

```
If(
    Not(IsBlankOrError(DataCardValue4.Text)),
    LookUp(EmployeeLookup, 'Employee Name' = DataCardValue4.Text, 'Employee Email'),
    "" 
)
```

Is anyone able to help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't see anything immediately wrong with what you have. What kind of control is `DataCardValue`? Is it a Modern text input? If you have renamed or changed properties in the SP List then do a data source refresh. Otherwise update your question with a screen grab of the formula so we can see any syntax highlighing issues/error msgs.